LAB: Enter two numbers and flip them
This is a lab I am absolutely stuck on.
The purpose is to take 2 numbers entered by a user and flip the display of them.
The example input provided is 3, 8.
A function is needed for this assignment and some parts were prefilled and can't be changed.
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2):
    val1 = user_val2
    val2 = user_val1
    
    return val1, val2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    input_val1 = input(int())
    input_val2 = input(int())

    print(*swap_values(input_val1, input_val2))

The output given is:
008 3

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I'm getting the 0's at the beginning.

Answered by metatoaster:
You are getting the 0 from the input(int()) call, where int() produces the default value of 0, and input() will print out the passed argument, in your case it would be what's returned by int(), thus resulting in the 0 being printed out. Try instead input() without any arguments
